# Скриншот скрытого окна

Tags: winapi, c++

Как получить изображение со скрытого окна?

Мой код получает лишь снимок той области и если что-то сверху есть, то его и получаю.

```
    int Grab(HWND hwnd){
        if(!hwnd) return 0;

        MRect rc; GetWindowRect(hwnd, rc);
        HDC dc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
        if(!dc) return 0;

        // Create compatible DC
        HDC cdc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);

        // Create a compatible bitmap
        HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, rc.GetW(), rc.GetH());

        // Select Bitmap
        HGDIOBJ odc=SelectObject(cdc, bmp);

        // Copy pixels from screen to the BITMAP
        int ret=BitBlt(cdc, 0, 0, rc.GetW(), rc.GetH(), dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        // Restore bitmap
        SelectObject(cdc, odc);

        // Create image
        if(ret) ret=NewHImage(bmp);

        DeleteObject(bmp);
        // Delete the hBitmapdc as you no longer need it
        DeleteDC(cdc);
        // Release the desktop device context handle
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, dc); 
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: А Вы уже пробовали посылать скрытому окну сообщение `WM_PRINT` со своим `HDC`?

Comment: Добавил PostMessage(hwnd, WM_PRINT, (WPARAM)cdc, 0); после Select Bitmap. Такой же эффект был при вызове BeginPaint(); Если окно видимо, то все равно получается снимок верхних окон, если скрыто, то черный экран.

Comment: >PostMessage(hwnd, WM_PRINT, (WPARAM)cdc, 0);

в `lParam` надо поместить какой-то флаг, например `PRF_NONCLIENT |PRF_CLIENT`.  
 --  
а еще не советую держать `HDC` данного окна во время работы `WM_PRINT` и рекомендую в данном случае вместо `Post` использовать `Send`.

Comment: >Такой же эффект был при вызове BeginPaint(); Если окно видимо, то все равно получается снимок верхних окон, если скрыто, то черный экран.

Что-то Вы не то делаете или не туда смотрите. `WM_PRINT` не умеет рисовать "братские" окна (о чем Вы как раз пишите). Максимум, дочерние или `popup`(только данного владельца) и только при условии, что указаны какие-то флаги из `PRF_CHILDREN` и `PRF_OWNED`.

Comment: @mikelsv, а с частично перекрытого окна такой код правильно снимает скриншот? Предполагаю, что да начиная с Windows Vista

Comment: Этот код принимает только то, что сверху. Нашел функцию PrintWindow(), она позволяет получать скриншот скрытого окна, но через раз возвращает черный квадрат и, при попытке делать скриншоты флеш приложения в firefox, в какой-то момент приводит к зависанию флеша. Я уже совершенно не понимаю, как делать нормальные скриншоты.

Comment: Помню, в `Camtasia Studio` была проблема при захвате экрана: периодически пропадали промежуточные кадры.  
 --  
Чтобы починить такую штуку приходилось отключать "аппаратное ускорение". Попробуйте.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [PrintWindow function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869(v=vs.85).aspx)