# Как получить скриншот окна чужого приложения?

Tags: c++, winapi

Хочу сделать программу, которая сыграла бы в обычный, виндовский сапер и выиграла бы. Для этого ей нужно видеть поле игры, дабы увидеть результат выбора клетки, мина там, цифра и прочее. Я хочу чтобы она сделала как бы "скриншот" поля после каждого выбора, и потом по нему уже ориентировалась. Как это сделать?

Comment: Проще написать свой сапер и к нему алгоритм разминирования, чем парсить картинку с экрана. :-)

Comment: Пусть отвечают наши хакеры

Comment: Наверняка есть как-то нормальный способ, но интересно, сработает ли послать саперу Alt+PrintScreen и достать скриншот из буфера обмена.

Comment: По сути область окна же ведь как-то перерисовывается, может ли это значить что буфер кадра можно как-то вычленить для дальнейшего использования?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Сработает, а куда оно денется. Можно и мышь программно двигать и автоматически нажимать на плитки. :-)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Скриншот скрытого окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269788/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: Не так давно решал похожую задачу, тоже для игрухи, капча экрана на заднем плане приложения, конвертация в 2 цвета, мышь и клавиатура на заднем плане приложения, можно [посмотреть тут](https://github.com/ClnViewer/GameDev/blob/4073847a87587b7babd3f622605bf1d2ad700ee2/HBitMap.cpp#L34)